# How can I add two registers' contents of different size to form an effective address in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-64, low-level

Consider the following incorrect instruction in x86 assembly:

```
imul    edx, [eax+cl], 2
```

Nasm complains that the effective address is incorrect. I understand that I cannot add two register contents of different size. How should that be done correctly? Maybe I should add somehow an offset - how can I do that in nasm? Note: I cannot add the whole ecx since higher bits contain data.

Comment: How about storing ecx in another register and then `and` it with 255 ?

Comment: What about movzx ecx,cl (unsigned) or movsx ecx,cl (signed)?

Comment: mov ebx,ecx xor ecx,ecx mov cl,bl imul edx,[eax+ecx] [link]http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/spr2002/books/labmanual/inst-ref-idiv.html

Answer (score 2):

One way is to store lower 8 bits of ecx like that: (guess it should work)

```
movzx   edx, cl
imul    edx, [eax+edx], 2
```

The other way is to run a block of self-modifying code replacing 'cl' with an 'immediate' offset updated by the app when needed. Note that modifying the code being run creates additional delays in newer CPUs, so it's rarely practical.